# If a,b,c are positive constants, $a>b$, then maximum value of $r^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a,b,c are positive constants, $a>b$, then maximum value of $r^2$, given by

$\frac{c^4}{r^2}= \frac{a^2}{sin^2\theta}+\frac{b^2}{cos^2\theta}$, must be

(A) $\frac{c^2}{a-b}$

(B)$\frac{c^2}{a+b}$

(C)$\frac{c^2}{sin^2\theta}$

(D)$\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{ab}}$

Comment: HInt  : maximum value of $r^2$ means minimum value of $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: r^2 is maximum when RHS is minimum.   You can replace sin^2 with x^2 and cos^2 with 1-x^2. And use the AM GM inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HInt : maximum value of $r^2$ means minimum value of $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$
as $a,b,c$ are constant  and $+$
so It means to minimize $\dfrac{c^4}{r^2}$ so 
$\to $Minimize $\frac{c^4}{r^2}= \frac{a^2}{sin^2\theta}+\frac{b^2}{cos^2\theta}=f(\theta)$
$$f(\theta)= \frac{a^2}{sin^2\theta}+\frac{b^2}{cos^2\theta}\\f(\theta)=a^2(1+cot^2\theta)+b^2(1+tan^2\theta)\\=a^2+b^2+a^2cot^2\theta+b^2tan^2\theta$$ we know $x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$
so 
$$f(\theta)=a^2+b^2+a^2cot^2\theta+b^2tan^2\theta\\\geq a^2+b^2+2\sqrt{a^2cot^2\theta\times b^2tan^2\theta}=a^2+b^2+2|a||b|\\$$we knew$a,b >0$ so 
$$f(\theta)\geq a^2+b^2+2ab=(a+b)^2\\min(f(\theta))=(a+b)^2$$
$$\dfrac{c^4}{r^2}=(a+b)^2 \\\to \dfrac{c^2}{r}=a+b \\\to r(max)=\dfrac{c^2}{a+b}$$

Comment: This means $\theta =\dfrac{k\pi}{4} \to sin^\theta=cos^2\theta = \frac12$ . then are you sure that question wants $r^2$ ...may be wants $r$?

Comment: I think Question wants $max(r)$ and it's "B"

Comment: Yeah probably that is when option B matches.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality on the right hand side and using $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta=1$:
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{\sin^2 \theta}+ \frac{b^2}{\cos^2 \theta}\right)\left(\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta\right)\geq(a+b)^2\implies RHS \geq(a+b)^2$$
Thus we have $$\frac{c^4}{r^2}\geq (a+b)^2\implies |r|\leq\frac{c^2}{a+b}$$ or equivalently $r^2\leq \frac{c^4}{(a+b)^2}$ since the question is asking about the maximum of $r^2$.